# ‘struct ...’ has no member named

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

Why do I keep getting this errors:

> struct has no members [-Wpedantic]
>  ‘struct cheque’ has no member named
>   ‘refc’
>  ‘struct cheque’ has no member named ‘valor’

etc. The code is as below

---

```
#ifndef _ITEM_
#define _ITEM_ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define key (a) (a != NULL ? a->refc : "")      
#define less (a,b) (strcmp (a,b)<0)
#define eq(a,b) (strcmp (a,b) == 0)
#define NULLitem NULL

typedef long int* Key;                  

typedef struct cheque {                 
    int valor
    long int refe
    long int refb
    long int* refc

}*Item;                         

Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int* refc);
void deleteItem (Item a);
void visitItem (Item a);

#endif
```

---

EDIT:

Now I'm facing folloeing errors,

> Item.c:6:36: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘refe’ Item
>   newItem (int valor, long item refe, long item refb, long item* refc) ^
>   Item.c: In function ‘visitItem’:
>
> Item.c:32:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but
>   argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=] printf("refe: %d\n",
>   a->refe); ^
>
> Item.c:33:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but
>   argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=] printf("refb: %d\n",
>   a->refb); The code is as below

**item.h**

```
#ifndef _ITEM_
#define _ITEM_ 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define key (a) (a != NULL ? a->refc : "")      
#define less (a,b) (strcmp (a,b)<0)
#define eq(a,b) (strcmp (a,b) == 0)
#define NULLitem NULL

typedef long int* Key;                  

typedef struct cheque {                 
    int valor;
    long int refe;
    long int refb;
    long int* refc;

}*Item;                         

Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int* refc);
void deleteItem (Item a);
void visitItem (Item a);

#endif
```

**item.c**

```
#include "Item.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


Item newItem (int valor, long item refe, long item refb, long item* refc)
{

    Item x = (Item) malloc (sizeof(struct cheque));

    x->valor = valor;
    x->refe = refe;
    x->refb = refb;
    x->refc = strdup(refc);

    return x;
}


void deleteItem (Item a)
{
    free(a->refc);
    free(a);

}


void visitItem (Item a)
{

    printf("valor: %d\n", a->valor);
    printf("refe: %d\n", a->refe);
    printf("refb: %d\n", a->refb);
    printf("refc: %ld\n", a->refc);

}
```

---

> EDIT_v2

```
Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int* refc)

printf("valor: %d\n", a->valor);
printf("refe: %ld\n", a->refe);
printf("refb: %ld\n", a->refb);
printf("refc: %p\n", a->refc);
```

After correcting those mistakes I got the following errors:

> Item.c: In function ‘newItem’: Item.c:14:2: warning: implicit
>    declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>
> x->refc = strdup(refc);   ^ Item.c:14:10: warning: assignment makes
>    pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]   x->refc =
>    strdup(refc);
>
> Item.c: In function ‘visitItem’: Item.c:34:2: warning: format ‘%p’
>   expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type  ‘long int
>   *’ [-Wformat=]   printf("refc: %p\n", a->refc);

**Edit_ v3**

1 problem fixed
Correction:

```
x->refc = refc;
```

Errors atm:

> Item.c: In function ‘visitItem’: Item.c:34:2: warning: format ‘%p’
>   expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int
>   *’ [-Wformat=]   printf("refc: %p\n", a->refc);

Comment: Essentially down to typos: you're missing plenty of `;`. Also consider replacing your macros with functions as the latter are easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolons:

```
typedef struct cheque {                 
    int valor;
    long int refe;
    long int refb;
    long int* refc;    

}*Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, your code should look like

```
typedef struct cheque {                 
    int valor;
    long int refe;
    long int refb;
    long int* refc;

}*Item;
```

with the `;`s.

---

EDIT:

I think, that's another typo.

```
Item newItem (int valor, long item refe, long item refb, long item* refc)
```

should read

```
Item newItem (int valor, long int refe, long int refb, long int* refc)
```

Then,

```
printf("refe: %d\n", a->refe);
printf("refb: %d\n", a->refb);
printf("refc: %ld\n", a->refc);
```

is having wrong *format specifiers* which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The correct format specifier for `long int` is `%ld`, and that for `long int *` is `%p`.

Also, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Damn, you are right, such a rookie mistake

Comment: @Miguel Never mind, happens. :-)

Comment: Thank you :)
Can you help me with my new erros :/ ? I am new to pointers, structs and FIFO stuff in C ..

Comment: @Miguel I would love to help, but please do not edit to remove the previous question. Simply __add__ below it your additional queries. Hope you understand. I've already rolled back your latest edit. Please edit accordingly,.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to stackoverflow.. I registered today... Sorry for not following the rules. How should I do then? should I "answer my question" to add a new querie?

Comment: @Miguel This time, I'll do the edits for you. :-) But be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here.

Comment: @Miguel updated your question and my answer. :-)

Comment: I have taken the tour, thank you for your help and editions
I just have one quesiton, where could I add my question that you edited? I tried to put it in a coment but it was too long, should I had to edit like you did?

Comment: @Miguel yes, obviously. Putting up a good question (which people would love to answer) is your job. I just gave an example by doing this edit. You need to do that now onwards. :-)

Comment: I have edited with a new question. But my post keeps getting down votes :( and was put as off topic :/

Comment: Could you help me with edit_v3  edition? I don't know how to fix that problem, the others I already did